# iMac not showing Airdrop discoverable options

Tags: iphone, imac, airdrop

I am trying to use Airdrop to send a file from my phone to my iMac, but when I am in the Airdrop folder in my iMac there are no options to make the machine discoverable.

Both devices are on the same wifi network, the phone (iPhone 6) is discoverable and has successfully used Airdrop to send to other devices.

If the 'make discoverable' options are not even showing in the Finder folder on my desktop how can I make these devices talk to each other?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, Charlie. My iMac is a late 2015 27" version.
If you have the same version and problems, it's probably a OS issue. Hopefully users report enough and force Apple aware of the issue in coming OS update.

My solution (somehow worked):

1. Make sure you have a connected Internet Cable or Wifi
2. Erase the Mac OS disk: press and hold CMD + R whilst the iMac start. Release since you see the Apple icon. Wait (it takes couple minutes)
3. Log-in screen will show several options then, including **Disk Utility**. Select it -> click on the Macintosh Disk in next windows (be careful: NOT CHOOSE THE HIDDEN IMAGE DISK) -> click Erase
4. Exit the Disk Utility windows
5. Now, you are in the initial screen. Choose **ReInstall Mac**. This takes you 3-4 hours with a good internet connection.
6. Your iMac after installation will be totally new. Keep in mind: Test AirDrop before installing ANY PROGRAM.

Unfortunately, as my observation, the AirDrop issue will happen again as soon as you begin to install certain softwares.

Hope Apple fix it soon.